# How to get list of Strings in hive from a json array

Tags: json, parsing, hive, hiveql

I have following json String

```json
{
  "userId": 12345,
  "eligibleCountries": [
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "MX"
    },
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "US"
    },
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "CA"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get

| userID | countries |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | ["MX","US","CA"] |

I can get ***userID*** using `GET_JSON_OBJECT` but for list of countries we can not use `GET_JSON_OBJECT`.
How can we get this in hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `[*]`

```
select get_json_object('{
  "userId": 12345,
  "eligibleCountries": [
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "MX"
    },
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "US"
    },
    {
      "Level": "COUNTRY",
      "Name": "CA"
    }
  ]
}','$.eligibleCountries[*].Name') as countries;
```